# How can I see the function arguments in a Clojure stacktrace?

Tags: debugging, clojure, stack-trace

How can I see the arguments passed to the functions in a Clojure stacktrace?

For example, how could I see what arguments were passed to `*get-item`, `*normalize-item-ref`, `outvalue-of`, `happiness`, and `nodestr` in this stacktrace? It would be nice to see how the program got to the error rather than just the error.

```
ERROR in (this-test) (workspace.clj:330)
Uncaught exception, not in assertion.
expected: nil
  actual: java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed: (item-or-item-ref? item-or-item-ref)
 at fargish.workspace$_STAR_get_item.invokeStatic (workspace.clj:330)
    fargish.workspace$_STAR_get_item.invoke (workspace.clj:330)
    fargish.workspace$_STAR_normalize_item_ref.invokeStatic (workspace.clj:365)
    fargish.workspace$_STAR_normalize_item_ref.invoke (workspace.clj:360)
    fargish.workspace$outvalue_of.invokeStatic (workspace.clj:815)
    fargish.workspace$outvalue_of.invoke (workspace.clj:810)
    fargish.workspace$outvalue_of.invokeStatic (workspace.clj:812)
    fargish.workspace$outvalue_of.invoke (workspace.clj:810)
    fargish.workspace$happiness.invokeStatic (workspace.clj:904)
    fargish.workspace$happiness.invoke (workspace.clj:902)
    fargish.workspace$nodestr.invokeStatic (workspace.clj:1039)
    fargish.workspace$nodestr.invoke (workspace.clj:1035)
    . . .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That information is not present in a stacktrace.

Comment: How else could I get it?

Comment: You have to add some code to the functions that are breaking, to make them print out information you want, or otherwise save it.

Comment: Ecch, that's what I've been doing. It's a pain. I've just spent two hours on a bug, and most of my mental effort has gone into hacking up ways to see what arguments are being passed without getting deluged with irrelevant stuff (since these functions get called a lot). I'm having goal-stack overflow. There has to be a better way. In practice, how do "real" Clojure programmers solve this problem?

Comment: Wrap the troublesome code paths in a try/catch; in the catch clause, rethrow a wrapping exception with information about whatever locals you care about. It's not ideal, because it's all manual and gross, and you have to keep all locals in scope while calling the subsidiary function, but it's really the best we've got. (unless you can figure out how to use a real JVM debugger in clojure, which is possible but not easy).

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I've accumulated some macros to help print stuff out, only when called from the right place (to prevent deluge), but I've always figured that a "real" Clojure programmer would know some simple way to do it, that would make me go "Oh! Duh!! Why didn't I think of that?" when I finally saw it. :) Oh well. It's surprising to me that gdb can do this on a C program without source code, and Clojure on the JVM can't.

Answer (score 2):

You can run sayid (http://bpiel.github.io/sayid/) on the namespace you are interested in. It will keep track of all function calls and arguments.

I think this is mostly useful for development/debugging. For production, the try-catch recommendation by amalloy above is probably best.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look. Indeed I only need this for development/debugging. I just want a simple way to find out what arguments were passed at each level on the stack without having to *think* so much.